# How do I exit a function with an error if a variable is None?

Tags: error-handling, rust, option-type

I am unsure which error handling I should use to exit a function with an error. I want something like:

```
fn somefn() {
    let x: Option<u64> = SomeOtherFn();
    ensure!(x is type u64, error); //exits somefn
}
```

Any way to exit `somefn` with custom err, if `SomeOtherFn` returns `None`.

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your question](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=439fe8e0527bcdeafc26dc3823f7a568).

Comment: I encourage you to reread [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/), especially the chapters on [enums](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-00-enums.html) and [recoverable errors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html). I'd follow that up with familiarizing yourself with the API surface of [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html)